# Changing image displayed in UIImage Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

My image exists in as tableView Cell so I am using the following code to make changes to it: (I am updating image from cache if there is any confusion below)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let nimage = cell.viewWithTag(111){   // 111 is a UIImageView

        nimage.image = imageCache[urlString]

        // above error - nimage has no member named image

        nimage = imageCache[urlString]

        // above error - cannot assign to 'let' value 'UIImage'

    }
```

what do I do?

Comment: you have to try image.image because you have said that 111 is an imageview

Comment: Sorry, that should say `nimage.image` see above edit

Comment: Still receive an error `nimage has no member named image`

Comment: `let nimage = cell.viewWithTag(111) as! UIImageView`

Comment: Oh my god, you're kidding me! What a rookie mistake

Comment: Try var nimage = cell.viewWithTag(111) instead of let nimage = cell.viewWithTag(111)

Comment: Worked for you or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type casting is a must here

```
 if let nimage:UIImageView = cell.viewWithTag(111) as! UIImageView{   // 111 is a UIImageView
        nimage.image = imageCache[urlString]
 }
```